# ImageResizer S3Reader vs. RemoteReader

Tags: image-resizing, imageresizer

As you can connect your S3 bucket to a simple domain like images.yourdomain.com, what is the advantage in using the S3Reader rather than simply using the RemoteReader?

I know that RemoteReader will open and resample all images for security reasons, but thats no problem.

Could I even switch between cloud providers by simply setting the nameserver to another destination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*You can use RemoteReader to connect to any public HTTP-accessible datastore, including Amazon S3.*

**However, S3Reader offers many benefits**

- Less error-prone whitelisting. Validate by bucket name instead of managing the permutations for each S3 region and address method.
- Optional file invalidation (RemoteReader cannot invalidate if a resource changes)
- Optional SSL encryption
- Optional IAM authentication so you can hide the source files, while serving resized versions.